# Flex 4 SWFLoader - Main app detecting events from remote sub app swf

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, sandbox, swfloader

I have 2 **separate** Flex 4 projects, **same framework** but running on **different servers**.

1) MainApp (IP:192.168.12.113:8080)

2) SubApp (IP:192.168.10.19:5080)

I need to integrate SubApp into MainApp and I have managed to do so using a SWFLoader.

```
//MainApp/mainapp.mxml
<s:SWFLoader id="contentLoader"
             loadForCompatibility="true"
             trustContent="true"
             source="http://192.168.10.19:5080/SubApp.swf"/> //Using url
```

Right now, I need the SubApp to notify the MainApp when a particular button is clicked so that the MainApp can perform some functions (E.g. Open/close a sliding window). How can I go about doing it?

In addition, to clarify, is this kind of setup considered as **multi-versioned remote sandbox**? Both applications are **trust-able** and should be able to **access each other variables/functions**.

Help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since they are in a differant domain, they are sandboxed applications. You can use the following for your case

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7f0d.html#WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7f00